# Reference Sheet name in Index Match by referring to value in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to use dynamic formulas...

I know that you can refer to a Sheet name in Excel using INDIRECT() with a value in the current sheet, e.g.

```
=INDIRECT("'" & INDIRECT("B" & ROW()) & "'! T32")
```

However, I want to refer to a sheet name using INDIRECT() within an INDEX MATCH Formula. The previous formula is not dynamic and can't be copied across all cells in a block.

The Manual version that works is:

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!$T$33:$AE$33,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN())),'Sheet1'!$T$32:$AE$32,0))
```

I have tried various ways to include an INDIRECT() as above instead of using the actual sheet name but have had no luck so far... any suggestions? The problem may be coming from the fact that I am referring to a range of cells, but I a still not sure how to get around this...

An example of what I have tried:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & INDIRECT("B", Row()) & "'!$T$33:$AE$33"),MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN())),'Sheet1'!$T$32:$AE$32,0))
```

The error I get is a #REF! error...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to reference a sheet other than the one the formula is in?

Comment: Yes! @Alexis Olson

Comment: How do you specify which sheet you are referring to? Do you have cells with the sheet names?

Comment: In your example, do you mean to try `=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("B"&row())...`?